# php files in phpmyadmin folder not executable

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

i have phpmyadmin on my amazon server installed ( in  /usr/share/phpMyAdmin  folder)

my phpMyAdmin.conf seems correct

i was able to access it from my browser before by typing https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin

After i restored my amazon instance from a snapshot , i can not access it anymore

i get this error :

```
Not Found
The requested URL /phpMyAdmin/navigation.php< was not found on this server.
```

Then i noticed Apache doesn't serve php files in that directory at all
Even when i put a minimal php file in that folder for test and point to it in browser, it will return it as a text file and i can see php codes in it!

I searched about it and found many similar issues, but none of them helped me
can anyone help me to find source of this issue?

ps: i have several virtual servers on my server and they are working fine.

here is a part of my phpMyAdmin.conf :

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
    </RequireAny>
  </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   # Apache 2.2
   Order Deny,Allow
   #Deny from All
   Allow from all
   Allow from ::1
 </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: That trailing `<` in `navigation.php<` belongs to the original error message or it got inserted when posting here?

Comment: Yes that belongs to the original message, thats because server doesn't execute php code and browser shows raw php codes. you search that message and Google will return million similar errors (including < character)  but none of them helped me to solve my problem :(

Comment: Are you saying that the default Apache behaviour to deal with unknown file types is to add a bogus `<` at the end of the URL and return a 404 Not Found status code, but send the file anyway?

Comment: No im not saying that. its not unknown file. it is a PHP file. i get raw php codes in browser because Apache doesnt run php codes which are in myphpadmin folder.

Answer (score 0):

use this to run files inside htdocs `localhost/navigation.php`

Comment: i dont get it, where should i use localhost/navigation.php to run files in htdocs? can you explain a little please?

Comment: inside htdocs create one folder example "test" inside test folder create one php file , jus paste following <?php echo "hi working";?> save it , open browser in url type localhost/test

Comment: yea, that works. but if i put it in phpMyAdmin installation folder, it does not